# Pass Javascript callback function to partial view MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, partial-views

I'm wondering if this is the right way of passing a JavaScript callback function to a partial view.  So depending on the view I'm on the partial view may do different things.  So I pass in a JavaScript call back function to achieve that.

Here is a generic function to call my partial view and where I pass in the JavaScript call back function.

```
 function showAjaxMessage(targetDiv, ajaxMessage) {    
    var ajaxLoader = "<img src='Content/loader.gif' alt=''>";
    $(targetDiv).html("<p>" + ajaxLoader + " " + ajaxMessage+"</p>"); 
}

function getPartialView(actionUrl, targetDiv, ajaxMessage, cbFunc) {
    showAjaxMessage(targetDiv, ajaxMessage);

    $.get(actionUrl, { callback: eval(cbFunc).toString()}, function(result) {
        $(targetDiv).html(result);
    });
}
```

Here is an example of me calling it:

```
 getPartialView("Home/OpenLogin", "#divLogon", "Loading...", function() { alert('This is the call back function!'); test(); });
```

Here is the controller where I get the callback function and save it to a model.  Then I pass it back to the partial view.

```
 // returns a login dialog which will be injected 
    // into a placeholder div on the client
    public ActionResult OpenLogin(string callback)
    {
        var baseModel = new BaseModel();
        baseModel.cbFunc = callback;

        return PartialView("LoginDialog", baseModel);
    }
```

Here is an example of my partial view.  Where you can see I get the call back function and set in the init function.

```
@model MvcApplication8.Models.BaseModel

function init(cb){
    if(cb!=undefined){
        cb();
    }
    else{
        alert("undefined");
    }
}

function test(){
    alert("Testing my call back");
}


$(function () {

   init(@Html.Raw(@Model.cbFunc));


});
```

The solution above works, but the main question that comes to mind is this the right way of doing it? Passing the call back function from the controller to the partial view sounds wrong, but how else would you do it? Any ideas?

Comment: Based on your example, I do not understand why would pass the callback function to a partial view. The partial view is rendered inside a div on the same page. Why not just declare the function on the page so that it's available to the rendered partial view?

Comment: Good point. The function is available once the partial view is rendered.

Comment: Does that solve your problem?

Comment: It certainly makes it more cleaner.  I like the idea of making anonymous functions, but passing to the controller and then back to the partial view sounds just wrong to me.

Comment: In that case, I have posted the comment as answer. You can mark it as accepted answer so that others would be benefited.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example, I do not understand why would pass the callback function to a partial view. The partial view is rendered inside a div on the same page. Why not just declare the function on the page so that it's available to the rendered partial view?

Comment: Consider the situation where the partial is used in multiple different parent pages. You shouldn't have to make the callback identical on all parents... and honestly it's kind of smelly to rely on what is effectively a global existing. If you pass it in, the partial only has to care about what it was given... and each parent page worries about the wire up. It would be much cleaner in my opinion...